# Java/UCanAccess Insert not working right

Tags: java, ms-access, gwt, ucanaccess

last week we got an assignment at school to develop a web Application for students, so they can use them to organize drives to school. The whole project is focused on project management and not on the programming part.
In my team we decided to make a GWT-Application because were all JAVA-Developers.

On the Server side I'm having trouble with our Microsoft Access DB I need to Insert a given dataset in the database, from the frontend I get an `createObject` which contains all the Information needed to be Insertet. My method looks like this:

```
    @Override
public void makeOffer(CreateObject createobject) {
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    if(!securityContext.getAuthentication().isAuthenticated()) {
        return;
    } 
    String userName = securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal().toString();
    String teacher = "n";
    if(userName.length() < 3) {
        teacher = "y";
    }
    String sql = "INSERT INTO T_FAHRTEN "
            + "(F_SEATS, F_FREESEATS, F_CAR, F_TIME, F_SMOKE, F_GENDER, F_TEACHER, F_INFOS, F_NAME, F_VORNAME, F_NUMMER, F_MAIL, F_STARTTOWN, F_STARTSTREET, F_STARTPLZ, F_DATE, F_USERNAME)"
            + "Values ("
            + "'" + createobject.getSeats() + "', "
            + "'" + createobject.getFreeSeats() + "', "
            + "'" + createobject.getCar() + "', "
            + "'" + createobject.getTime() + "', "
            + "'" + createobject.getSmoke() + "', "
            + "'" + createobject.getGender() + "', "
            + "'" + teacher + "', "
            + "'" + createobject.getInfo() + "', "
            + "'" + createobject.getName() + "', "
            + "'" + createobject.getVorname() + "', "
            + "'" + createobject.getTelNummer() + "', "
            + "'" + createobject.getEmail()+ "', "
            + "'" + createobject.getStartStadt() + "', "
            + "'" + createobject.getStartStreet() + "', "
            + "'" + createobject.getStartPlz()+ "', "
            + "'" + createobject.getDate() + "', "
            + "'" + userName + "'"
            + ");";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stm = null;

    try {
        //FIXME 
        String dbURL = getClass().getResource("Drive2Gether2School1.accdb").getPath();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + dbURL);
        stm = conn.createStatement();
        stm.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("==> error creating");
        e.printStackTrace();
        //TODO implement Error Handling
    } finally {
        try {
            if(stm != null) stm.close();
            if(conn != null) conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("==> error closing");
            //TODO implement Error Handling
        }
    }
    System.out.println("==> offer createt");
}
```

The Problem is, the data doesnt't get Insertet into the Access DB. 
Actual its kinda weird, I have a method which gives me everything from the table and shows it on the Frontend. And If I insert something and then show everything I see the stuff I just insertet, but if I open the Tabel in MS-Access the Inserts are not there.
I already tried `conn.commit` and `conn.setAutoCommit(true)` both not helping.

Comment: Have your code display the value of `dbURL` after you assign it. You may be looking at two different copies of your Access database.

Comment: @GordThompson ....I had the file MyAccessDB.accdb in my Server package, when I try to launch my Application it uses the MyAccessDB.accdb from my target directory, youre right, I was looking at a different copy of the file

Comment: You are inserting all values as if they were text. Date and time values must be wrapped in octothorpes, not single-quotes, and numbers nothing at all.

Comment: BS in Engineering, MS in CS, 20 years of teaching IT and CS .... I had to Google 'octothorpes'.